# Swift: Storing a Dictionary/Array of a Custom Object in a Core Data Managed Object Property

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to implement the following 'Session' object in Core Data. All properties except the exerciseLog can be saved and accessed properly in Core Data. The way I currently have this set up allows me to manipulate the 'Session' object instance when it is in memory once it has been created, but upon saving the ManagedContext, the Object does not save exerciseLog property persistently and it is stored as nil instead. 
     This likely happens because when the object is in memory the transient value of the exerciseLog property can be manipulated, but the persistent storage of it is not implemented. I do not know how to properly implement the ability to allow the exerciseLog dictionary; with String key, and value as a custom object, 'Set' array, to be stored when the managed context is saved. The Set object is not a managed object by Core Data. It is just a regular object that the Session Object should reference and store (i.e not involved in the object graph with relationships). Note: I imagine if there is a solution for this, then it would also work if the 'Set' class was a struct, which would have been my preference.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Session)
class Session: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var exerciseLog: [String: [Set]]
    @NSManaged var sessionDate: NSDate
    @NSManaged var sessionDuration: NSNumber
    @NSManaged var routineForSession: Routine

}


class Set:  NSObject, Printable{
    var reps: Int!
    var weight: Double!


}
```

[image: Core Data Schema]

[image: Managed Object]

Comment: you could make it a transient property and store it as NSData, de-archiving and archiving it as a Dictionary

Comment: An undefined entity attribute in your data model will not work. each attribute must have a data type.